# Converting JSON to C# involving a large number of nested JSON objects

Tags: c#, json

I would like to convert (deserialize) JSON into C#. I have taken a stab at it by creating a C# file that will handle the serialization and deserializtion.

Given a JSON file that contains

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Weekly Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-06-26",
        "4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Weekly Time Series": {
        "2020-06-26": {
            "1. open": "122.1200",
            "2. high": "122.9000",
            "3. low": "115.8800",
            "4. close": "117.1900",
            "5. volume": "35016186"
        },
        "2020-06-19": {
            "1. open": "119.1900",
            "2. high": "127.5000",
            "3. low": "118.2900",
            "4. close": "122.4700",
            "5. volume": "24867689"
        },
        "2020-06-12": {
            "1. open": "132.2700",
            "2. high": "135.8800",
            "3. low": "117.8352",
            "4. close": "121.9100",
            "5. volume": "33456639"
        },
        [...]

        "2000-07-07": {
            "1. open": "108.7500",
            "2. high": "109.8700",
            "3. low": "100.0000",
            "4. close": "105.0600",
            "5. volume": "38608400"
        }
    }
}
```

[...] being a large number of objects

the file:
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo

Here is my C# classes.
I can't figure out how to

1. Convert the JSON object names into proper C# variables ex "1. open" -> "open"
2. Deserialize

```
    public class PeriodData
    {
        public string open { get; set; }
        public string high { get; set; }
        public string low { get; set; }
        public string close { get; set; }
        public string volume { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Period
    {
        private IEnumerable<PeriodData> periodData { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class MetaData
    {
        public string info { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public string lastRefreshed { get; set; }
        public string timeZone { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Root
    {
        public MetaData metaData { get; set; }
        public Period period { get; set; }
    }
```

If I was to deserialize the JSON object I would call

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); //Create a client to retrieve the file
var JSONserverdata = client.GetStringAsync(url); // Get the stock data
                                                 // url ->location of the file on the server
var Cdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(JSONserverdata) //Deserialize the stock data into C#
```

*I don't need to serialize this object but if you want to answer that, go ahead*

Comment: `period` should be some form of `Dictionary<DateTime,PeriodData>`, add `[JsonProperty("name")]` to rename fields.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to create classes representing the object types, just deserialize as a `JObject` or if you don't know the structure ahead of time, a `JToken`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dictionary<DateTime, PeriodData>` for different dates and you should use `[JsonProperty("string")]` to define the name of the properties from json. Here is a working example,

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
    public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Weekly Time Series")]
    public Dictionary<DateTime, PeriodData> Period { get; set; }
}

public class MetaData
{
    [JsonProperty("1. Information")]
    public string Info { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2. Symbol")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("3. Last Refreshed")]
    public string LastRefreshed { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("4. Time Zone")]
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
}

public class PeriodData
{
    [JsonProperty("1. open")]
    public string Open { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2. high")]
    public string High { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("3. low")]
    public string Low { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("4. close")]
    public string Close { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("5. volume")]
    public string Volume { get; set; }
}

// And in your main,
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

// And you can print the whole json by serializing it.
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented));

// You can access any property or dictionary stored under Period.
Console.WriteLine(obj.Period.Count); // prints 4
```